# NoRecordExists inputfilter

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have a fieldset which is used in both an 'add' and 'edit' form.

The fieldset implements `InputFilterProviderInterface` to provide its validation.

When validating for an add operation, I need to check a database record with the same value doesn't already exist in the database, so I use the `NoRecordExists` validator.

All good so far.  But, when I use the same fieldset in an edit form, the validation will fail, as there is obviously already a record with a specific value, its the record being edited.

So I turn to the `exclude` option of the `NoRecordExists` validator and exclude the record with the 'id' (this is my primary key field) of the record I'm editing.

So I'm nearly there, the only thing I can't work out is how to get the 'id' value which I want to exclude at the point I create the inputfilter in `getInputFilterSpecification`.

Here is my fieldset code.  If anyone can tell me how to access other properties of the form (or bound object) from within `getInputFilterSpecification` I would me much obliged.

Maybe I need to implement my imputfilter differently to do this?  Or even implement a custom validator?  But surely a custom validator would be overkill for what would seem a pretty regular use case...

Many thanks in advance.
:wq

```
<?php
namespace Kickoff\Form\Competition;

use Kickoff\Form\AbstractFieldset,
    Kickoff\Model\Entities\Competition,
    DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject as DoctrineHydrator,
    Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterProviderInterface;


class CompetitionFieldset extends AbstractFieldset implements InputFilterProviderInterface
{
    public function init()
    {
        $this->setName('Competition')
            ->setHydrator(new DoctrineHydrator($this->getObjectManager(),'Kickoff\Model\Entities\Competition'))
            ->setObject(new Competition())
            ->setLabel('Competition')
            ->setAttribute('class','form-collection');

        $this->add(array(
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Hidden',
            'name' => 'id',
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'name',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Competition name',
                'admin_inline' => true,
            ),
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'long_name',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Competition long name',
                'admin_inline' => true,
            ),
            'attributes' => array(
                'class' => 'input-xxlarge',
            ),
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Collection',
            'name' => 'leagues',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Leagues',
                'count' => 0,
                'should_create_template' => true,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'target_element' => array(
                    'type' => 'LeagueFieldset',
                ),
            ),
        ));
    }


    /**
     * Implement InputFilterProviderInterface
     */
    public function getInputFilterSpecification()
    {
        return array(
            'name' => array(
                'filters'  => array(
                    array('name' => 'Zend\Filter\StringTrim'),
                ),
                'validators' => array(
                    'notempty' => array(
                        'name' => 'NotEmpty',
                        'break_chain_on_failure' => true,
                        'options' => array(
                            'messages' => array('isEmpty' => 'Competition name is required.',),
                        ),
                    ),
                    'length' => array(
                        'name' => 'StringLength',
                        'options' => array(
                            'max' => '64',
                            'messages' => array(
                                'stringLengthTooLong' => 'Competition name must be no more than 64 characters.',
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                    'unique' => array(
                        'name' => 'Db\NoRecordExists',
                        'options' => array(
                            'table' => 'competition',
                            'field' => 'name',
                            'adapter' => $this->serviceManager->getServiceLocator()->get('db'),
                            'exclude' => array(
                                'field' => 'id',
                                'value' => '',
                            ),
                            'messages' => array(
                                'recordFound' => 'A competition already exists with this name',
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            'long_name' => array(
                'filters'  => array(
                    array('name' => 'Zend\Filter\StringTrim'),
                ),
                'validators' => array(
                    'length' => array(
                        'name' => 'StringLength',
                        'options' => array(
                            'max' => '128',
                            'messages' => array(
                                'stringLengthTooLong' => 'Competition long name must be no more than 128 characters.',
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

Edit: adding my 'edit' controller action to this post:

```
public function editCompetitionAction()
{
    $id = $this->params()->fromRoute('competition_id');

    $repository = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('Kickoff\Model\Entities\Competition');
    $competition = $repository->find($id);

    if (null == $competition) {
        $this->getResponse()->setStatusCode(404);
        return;
    }

    $formManager = $this->serviceLocator->get('FormElementManager');
    $form = $formManager->get('Kickoff\Form\Competition\CompetitionForm');
    $form->bind($competition);

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->isPost()) {
        $form->setData($request->getPost());
        $this->logger->debug("Validator is ".print_r($form->getValidator(),1));
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $this->getEntityManager()->persist($competition);
            $this->getEntityManager()->flush();
        }
    }

    return array(
        'form' => $form,
    );
}
```

Comment: You access the validator from the controller after the form has been sent and then you modify the validator to your desire ;)

Comment: Thanks Sam, I'm going to have a look into this and Andrew's suggestion below.

Answer (score 1):

It would be simpler to check that condition outside of the InputFilter.

If you do this then you can use the same form for both update and insert.

You could either a) Use a separate action to update and insert (CRUD) or b) if you want them to update/insert on a condition do something like this

```
// form validates for update or insert now...

if($form->isValid()) {
    if($mapper->exists($object)) {
        $mapper->update($object);
    }
    else {
        $mapper->save($object);
    }
}
```

Comment: Andrew, thanks for your comment.  I'm actually using Doctrine to manage my entities, so the CRUD insert/update is taken care of for me, simply by persisting the existing or new entity.  I'll have a look at validating the duplicate outside of the form validation.  Also, I'll update my original post to include my 'edit' controller action.

Answer (score 1):

Here I found solutions for both **Add Action** and **Edit Action**

***Controller:***

In `addAction:`

```
            $postData = $this->request->getPost ();
            $dbAdapter = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
            $form->setInputFilter(new FormFilter($dbAdapter));
            $form->setData ($postData);
            if (!$form->isValid ()) {
                $viewModel->error = true;
                return $viewModel;
            }
```

In `editAction:`

```
            $post = $request->getPost();
            $dbAdapter = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');                
            $form->setInputFilter(new FormFilter($dbAdapter,$Id));
            $form->setData ($post);
            $Id = $post['id'];
            if (!$form->isValid ()) {
                    $viewModel->error = true;
                    $viewModel->Id = $Id;
                    $viewModel->form = $form;
                    return $viewModel;
            }
```

In ***Form Filter*** file:

```
class FormFilter extends InputFilter {

    public function __construct ($dbAdapter, $id = '')
    {
        $this->dbAdapter = $dbAdapter;
        $this->add(array(
                'name'       => 'name',
                'required'   => true,
                'filters'  => array(
                        array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                        array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                ),
                'validators' => array(
                        array(
                                'name'    => 'StringLength',
                                'options' => array(
                                        'encoding' => 'UTF-8'
                                ),
                        ),
                        array(
                                'name'    => 'Zend\Validator\Db\NoRecordExists',
                                'options' => array(
                                        'table' => 'test',
                                        'field' => 'name',
                                        'adapter' => $this->dbAdapter,
                                        'exclude' => array(
                                                'field' => 'id',
                                                'value' => $id,
                                        ),
                                        'messages' => array(
                                                \Zend\Validator\Db\NoRecordExists::ERROR_RECORD_FOUND => 'The specified name already exists in database'
                                        ),
                                ),
                        ),
                ),
        ));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this validator in this case is wrong.

What happens: The validator sends a SELECT query to the database. If it finds something, it will report "invalid".

If it does not find something, it will report "valid", but what if at the same time a second request does the same and also gets back a "valid". Who wins? And how is the failing of one query handled, because obviously you want to write the input to the database?

This is calles a [TOCTOU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use) problem. Writing unique records to the database should only be done by just trying to insert the new record and wait for the database to complain about non-unique index violation. This is then an expected outcome of the write operation and can be handled.

The validator is not useless: You can still use it to check if there is something in the way in the database, e.g. in an Ajax query when the user is in the process of filling in his username etc. Checking and getting a boolean value from the database *for read purposes only* is completely ok. But as an input validator, this is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This is my working solution:

```
$inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
            'name'     => 'role_name',
            'required' => true,
            'filters'  => array(
                array('name' => 'StripTags')
            ),
            'validators' => array(
                array(
                    'name'    => 'StringLength',
                    'options' => array(
                        'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                        'min'      => 2,
                        'max'     => 15
                    ),
                ),
                array(
                    'name'    => 'Zend\Validator\Db\NoRecordExists',
                    'options' => array(
                        'table' => 'user_role',
                        'field' => 'code',
                        'adapter' => \Zend\Db\TableGateway\Feature\GlobalAdapterFeature::getStaticAdapter(),
                        'messages' => array(
                            \Zend\Validator\Db\NoRecordExists::ERROR_RECORD_FOUND => 'The specified name already exists in database' 
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        )));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to this problem.
Basically the default NoRecordExists validator expects the value along with the column to be excluded in the configuration parameters. This can be changed in the controller as mentioned by Ritesh; I played around for a while and got this solution.

I am using the context array variable which is available in isValid function. Instead of sending the id value, you send in the value of the form field to pick up from

in the InputFilter you have the following

```
$this->add ( array (
    'name'  => 'user_email',
    'required' => true,
    'filters' => array (
        array ( 
            'name' => 'StringTrim',
        ),
        array ( 
            'name' => 'StripTags',
        ),
    ),
    'validators' => array (
        array (
            'name' => 'EmailAddress',
            'options' => array (
                'domain' => true,
            )
        ),
        array (
            'name' => 'Application\Validator\NoRecordExists',
            'options' => array (
                'table' => 'user',
                'field' => 'user_email',
                'adapter' => \Zend\Db\TableGateway\Feature\GlobalAdapterFeature::getStaticAdapter( ),
                'exclude' => array(
                    'field' => 'user_id',
                    'formvalue' => 'user_id',
                ),
            )
        ),

    )
) );
```

There is an hidden element user_id defined in the form; the value set there is used inside checking

```
<?php

namespace Application\Validator;

class NoRecordExists extends \Zend\Validator\Db\NoRecordExists {

    public function isValid( $value, $context=array( ) ) {

        $exclude = $this->getExclude( );

        if( is_array( $exclude ) ){
            if ( array_key_exists( 'formvalue', $exclude ) ) {
                $formvalue = $exclude[ 'formvalue' ];
                $exclude[ 'value' ] = $context[ $formvalue ];
                $this->setExclude( $exclude );
            }
        }

        return parent::isValid( $value );

    }

}
```

Hope this helps